# Screen Saver Does Not Show When On Battery

Tags: 10.04, battery, screensaver

I use gnome-screensaver on my system, and it operates near my expectations.  One question.  Is there a way to get the screensaver to show up  when the system is operating on battery power only?  Right now, the system just blanks the screen, but I'd really like to see an actual screensaver when I blank my screen.  Any way to do this?

Comment: This is done because running the screen saver takes more power and will run your battery down faster.

Comment: @psusi: yes, but i've got insane battery life on this system.  I'd love to have the screensaver show up anyways (since the display goes to sleep within 5 minutes anyways)

Comment: Does the display go to sleep before the screensaver comes up?

Comment: nope, on battery, the screensaver just doesn't load at all (the screen is set to not go to sleep until a time period that is long after the screensaver kicks in)

Answer (score 2):

Open Settings → Power Management Preferences, select the On Battery Power tab, and adjust the “Put display to sleep when inactive for” option to suit your needs.

Comment: There aren't 60 settings available.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this counts as an answer, but If you open up the Screensaver application from the dash, there's a slider near the bottom that sets when the computer is regarded as idle. Make sure that number is not higher than the setting for when to put the computer to sleep.   That might work.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't have an effect either.